# tryPattern String method

Tags: java, string, class

I'm doing the Mastermmind game in Java with every method separeted and organized, like this:

```
public int setnPositions(int nPositions) {
   ...
}

public int setnRows(int nRows) {
   ...
}

public int setnColors(int nColors) {
   ...
}
```

My question is about one particular method called "tryPattern". This method compares the mainString to the guessString.

This method is contained in the main class like this:

```
public Classification tryPattern(String tryKey) {
}
```

Of course I created another class called "Classisfication" which handles the comparison between two strings and atributes the number of black and white pins.

The question is, how do I do that in the class "Classification" and then call it back in the main class on the "tryPattern" method.

Hope I explained myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
public class MyClass {
  ...
  Classification classification = new Classification();
  boolean result = classification.tryPattern(somePatternString);
  ...
}
```

You will need to modify your Classification class.

```
public class Classification {
  public boolean tryPattern(){
    // TO DO
  }
}
```

That being said, I think in this case, tryPattern could just be a method in your main class with no need for you to create the Classification class at all.

Comment: I was wondering about this for a few minutes then i figured out a way to implement your answer with the Classification class. I really need to have that class. It's a required method. Thank you for the help!